# Why should a POJO be ordinary and not special?

Tags: java, pojo

Why does POJO object should not extend any class, implement interface or have any annotations

Comment: I hate to phrase it like this, but... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object

Answer (score 13):

It's about freedom.

[image]
[image]

When you write a class that does not extend any other class, nor implement an interface: you can do anything you want - no one dictates what you can and can't do. Apart from traditional Java syntax, you are not bound by anything else. Think about the flexibility this offers.

This feature of POJOs allow them to be tested and developed independently. All you need to think about is what your class should be doing.

POJOs should be ordinary because their usefulness is grounded on the fact that they *are* ordinary.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't really make sense to ask.  POJO is a label for classes [with those properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object).  If class doesn't have those properties then it isn't a POJO class.

It is a bit like asking why can't a bicycle have only one wheel<sup>1</sup>.  And the answer to that is because it had only one wheel it would be a unicycle not a bicycle.

<sup>1 - This example is carefully chosen to avoid the challenging terminological problem of bicycles with *training wheels*. :-)</sup>